# Как сверстать стул как на картинке?

Tags: html, css, css3, svg

Как сверстать такой стул, как на картинке, чтобы ножки не вылезали, а сиденье вылезало за пределы круга?

[image: тут должна быть картинка стула]

Comment: нужно очень точно обвести сиденье по контуру или же иметь сиденьеотдельной картинкой

Comment: Самое простое что можно сделать, так просто взять эту картинку и вставить её. А не верстать всё это. В основном так и делают

Answer (score 5):

Я бы сделал так:

Берём фотку стула (нашёл в инете вот такой)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее заходи в ФШ, подставляем под него круг и обрезаем как хотим.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По факту уже всё, сохраняем результат и ставим через `<img>` или `background`..

---

Ещё можно сделать круг при помощи элемента.
Но я бы советовал сделать именно как описано выше.

```css
.curcle {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #07f;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.curcle > img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="curcle">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5RYv.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Решение неплохое, но вот что делать, если надо, чтобы при скролле ножка стула как бы вылазила из-за круга (эффект parallax). Тут получается никак не сверстать такое.

Comment: @ДаниилКедров, это нужно было указывать в вопросе. Это уже посложнее.

Comment: Чисто технически невозможно переплести слои, значит придётся отделять ножки стула от сиденья в фотошопе, а потом при помощи position: absolute; подгонять. По другому наверное никак.

Answer (score 5):

**Внимание!** Решение **НЕ** универсальное и **ОЧЕНЬ** ситуационное. В частности, если фон однородный и вокруг много свободного места (но необязательно).

**P.S.** Вместо *margin* можно использовать и *transform*.

```css
body{
    margin:100px;
}
.circle{
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    border-radius:100%;
    background:blue;
    position:relative;
}
.circle::before{
    content:"";
    width:100%;
    height:50%;
    background:transparent;
    border-bottom-left-radius:400px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:400px;
    border:100px solid #fff;
    border-top:0 none;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-100px;
    left:-100px;
    z-index:2;
}
.circle img{
    width:100%;
    margin:-50px 0 0 -50px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    transition:margin 0.3s;
}
.circle:hover::before{
    opacity:0;
}
.circle:hover img{
    margin-top:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9vBr.png" alt=" />
</div>
```